# ProxyPass but exclude certain sub directory

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

This is what I need to achieve
I need to proxy all requests to /public/ route to another server, except that requests to /public/forms/ must not be proxied and should be served by this apache server.

I have added these directives to my httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass            /public/    http://localhost:3002/public/ retry=10
ProxyPassReverse     /public/    http://localhost:3002/public/
```

It proxies all requests to /public/ to this localhost:3002 but is there any way to exclude /public/forms/ from this proxying?

Answer (score 21):

On top of those because most specific requests should be defined first with ProxyPass add this:

```
ProxyPass /public/forms/ !
```

That tells mod_proxy to "not proxy" for that path and subdirectories.